# Conditional Formatting based on Lookup Result Value

Tags: excel, format, vlookup

On Sheet 1, I have a yearly calendar (seen below for example), and on Sheet 2 I have a table of events with their dates and corresponding event info.

[image]

The numbers on the calendars are full dates such as 1/1/2019, but are formatted to just show the day.

***What I want to figure out is how to highlight the dates on the yearly calendar different colors based on the status of the event (Scheduled, Planned, Completed, or Holiday) for that given date.***

Here is the Table on Sheet 2 
[image]

For example, if 1/1/2019 is Scheduled, then that date on the yearly calendar should be colored blue.

I figure I will need multiple conditional formatting rules to accomplish this. The normal vlookup to return the status of the date on E10 is  `=VLOOKUP(E10,'2019 Events'!C6:M371,2,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the combination of `SUMPRODUCT` and `N` for lookups with different columns. In your case the formular for E10 would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(E10='2019 Events'!$C$6:$C$371);N("Scheduled"='2019 Events'!$D$6:$D$371)) > 0
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` returns `1` (or more) for found and `0` for not found. Use four conditional formattings, one for each event status.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. And also, how would I apply this formula to all the cells since it's only referencing E10?

Comment: You may apply conditional formattings to ranges of cells with a single formular. Just ask Google. Note that other than fixed cell references (marked with `$`) relative cell references (like the `E10` in the formular above) are taken for the first cell of the range only while for all other cells in the range relative cell references are "translated" to correspond their distance to the first cell.

Comment: I updated my answer to make the formular return a boolean value (I added a `> 0`).

Comment: I see what you mean for it will apply to the entire range. However, the formula doesn't seem to work still. Nothing changes on the sheet.

Comment: For me it works. Select January (`C9:I13`), than add a conditional formatting with option _Use a formular to determine which cells to format_. Enter the adjusted formular (you have to replace `E10` by the reference to the first cell of the range: `C9`). Assumed the event sheet is named "2019 Events" it should work. At least it does for me.

Comment: I got it to work by replacing the semicolon with a comma! Perfectly does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Ahh! I use the German Excel version and just translated the function names. Didn't realize the different delimiter.